# Summation limits with change of variables

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, summation

I have the following sum (this is the context of QFT for period finding):

> [image: Blockquote]

I am having trouble understaning the change in variables from line (1) to line (2).

I understand the sum over m gives constructive interference only if ar/N is integer, in which case each term in the sum is equal to one, and the sum is N/r.

By defining $ar/N = l $ we have $l=0$ in the bottom. However at the top i don't understand how $N-1$ changes to $r-1$

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

We show the following identity is valid:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{r}}{N}\sum_{a=0}^{N-1}\exp\left(2\pi i a_0\frac{a}{N}\right)
\sum_{m=0}^{\frac{N}{r}-1}\exp\left(2\pi i\frac{a r}{N}m\right)
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{l=0}^{r-1}\exp\left(2\pi i a_0\frac{l}{r}\right)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

As OP already indicated we use here a *[series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection)* :
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=0}^{\frac{N}{r}-1}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi im a}{\frac{N}{r}}\right)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{N}{r}&\qquad \frac{N}{r}\mid a\\
0& \qquad \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{r}}{N}\sum_{a=0}^{N-1}}&\color{blue}{\exp\left(2\pi i a_0\frac{a}{N}\right)
> \sum_{m=0}^{\frac{N}{r}-1}\exp\left(2\pi i\frac{a r}{N}m\right)}\\
> &=\frac{\sqrt{r}}{N}\sum_{{a=0}\atop{\frac{N}{r}\mid a}}^{N-1}\exp\left(2\pi i a_0\frac{a}{N}\right)\frac{N}{r}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{{a=0}\atop{\frac{N}{r}\mid a}}^{N-1}\exp\left(2\pi i a_0\frac{a}{N}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{l=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{(N-1)r}{N}\right\rfloor}\exp\left(2\pi i a_0\frac{l}{r}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{l=0}^{r-1}\exp\left(2\pi i a_0\frac{l}{r}\right)}\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we apply the series multisection (2).
- In (4) we make a change of the index variable $l:=\frac{a\cdot r}{N}$. This way we skip all the zero terms according to the series multisection. We also use the *[floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* function to specify the upper limit of the sum.
- In (5) we simplify the upper limit of the sum
  \begin{align*}
  \left\lfloor\frac{(N-1)r}{N}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor r-\frac{r}{N}\right\rfloor=r-1
  \end{align*}
  since $0< \frac{r}{N}<1$.